# How can I view SWT Image while debugging?

Tags: debugging, swt, eclipse-rcp

I added a breakpoint on my SWT-based application, and when Eclipse stops at it during a debug session I want to view the image referenced by an `Image` variable.

If I right click the variable and choose *watch* or *inspect*, all I see is what is returned from `Image`'s `toString` method.

Is it possible?

Comment: You are generating that image on the fly..? Or why do you want to see it..? You can ask for width/height by `img.getImageData().width` if it helps you somehow..

Comment: I'm drawing it on the fly, and I'd like to see how it is in an specific point in time.

Comment: May I see the code of generation..?

Comment: I create a new GC passing my Image to it and draw a few dozens of squares and lines.  That's it.

Comment: You can create some method which will save the image to some uniquely name file on each step of you generating algorithm..

Comment: Hm... that's an interesting idea.

Comment: So you can use timestamp as a name of saved image and you'll get the progress in time as you want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debug views cannot "show" an image. The custom "Detail Formatters" can only return a string to be shown, not an `Image` or `ImageDescriptor`. It would make for a very nice extension though...

Comment: Don't you know if there's a plugin for that?

Comment: None that I know of... I'm not even sure how to do it... You probably want to add a new item to the popup menu of the Variables view. The selection seems to be an `JDILocalVariable`... but I haven't tried to decipher this...

Answer (score 1):

You could add a few lines of code that save the `Image` to your disc, then you can view the image.